# Searching for file with a name in IntelliJ IDEA community edition 14 on Mac

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

So I have used Intellij Idea on Ubuntu before and the shortcut for "searching a file with a name in the project directory" used to be

> > Ctrl + Shift + n

**I have tried**

> > command + Shift + n
> >
> > control + Shift + n

but if just opens a "New scratch" dialog. Does anyone know whats the correct shortcut in the Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortcut on OS X is <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (at least in the *OS X 10.5+ keymap*, which should be default).

Or you can use more universal shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> ([*Search everywhere*](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/searching-everywhere.html) action) which is the same on Windows/OS X/Linux and searches through classes, symbols, files, etc.

[Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf) is also a convenient list of important IntelliJ shortcuts on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

If by some reason the default keymap is changed, there are several ways to see the actual shortcut:

- open "Main Menu > Navigate" and see what is the shortcut in frong of "File ..." sub menu;
- open "Help > Find Action" and type "navigate file", the shortcut will be displayed in front of the action;
- open "File > Settings > Keymap" and search for "navigate file" action, again the shortcut will be displayed in front of the action.